# base64_encode() function is not working with equal to (==) operator.

Tags: php, encoding, base64, urlencode, urldecode

```
$url = get_url(CONFIRM,base64_encode($_POST['status']."|".$agent_id));
ta_send_verification($_POST['email'],$_POST['agent_name'],$url);
```

I'm sending the profile confirmation mail to user profile. That mail contains activation url link. When I click that link I got this url

**Wrong url**

```
MlJPSEU0WEFKVlNZSFZFRFVXMlk1VVpUUTBIRk1KT0w0WDVBUzNVMnwyNA==
```

**Correct url**

```
MlJPSEU0WEFKVlNZSFZFRFVXMlk1VVpUUTBIRk1KT0w0WDVBUzNVMnwyNA
```

Second url is the correct one and it works fine too. But, In my activation link I always get the url with this `==` equal to symbol. I don't know how can I remove that `==` equal to symbol in my activation url link?

Comment: Instead you can also use the following encoding function.
'convert_uuencode'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a default behaviour of the `base64_encode()` as `==` is nothing but padding.

From the [wikipedia of base64 encoding..](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding)

> The '==' and '=' sequence indicate that the last group contained only
>   8 or 16 bits, respectively.

To remove that, simple do a `str_replace()` for the double equal symbol.

```
$url = get_url(CONFIRM,base64_encode($_POST['status']."|".$agent_id));
$url = str_replace('==','',$url);
```

Comment: $url = str_replace('==','',$url);
Dont write this,
$url = str_replace('=','',$url); //write this way,

Answer (score 0):

This answer is old, but it would be a bit safer to do a `trim()` because then we know we're just removing stuff at the start/end.

example:

```
function getCleanBase64(string $my_string): string {
    return trim(base64_encode($my_string), '=');
}

echo getCleanBase64('test');
```